# Unexpected positioning of empty <span> in Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

```html
<div>This <span>.</span> is <span style="display:inline-block"></span> a <span></span> sentence</div>
```

This example is also available in https://jsbin.com/takeromoxo/edit?html,output.

The first `<span>` that has a period in it is positioned as expected between "This" and "is", so does the second one that is inline-block. However the empty `<span>` is positioned at the beginning of wrapper `<div>` instead of between "a" and "sentence".

This weird behavior applies to Chrome and Safari. Firefox however does position the empty `<span>` tag between text nodes, which is what I expected.

Is this a bug in webkit?

Comment: Position it how? It's unclear what the issue is. An empty span is invisible.

Comment: Unable to duplicate; see https://jsbin.com/nutunamige/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I think adding the border style fixes the behavior. Please remove any custom style on the span and use inspector tool to select elements. I think you will see what I meant :)

Comment: @Paulie_D It is invisible but still an element in the DOM tree, you can still get where it is positioned using Chrome dev tool. For some background, I was dealing with a piece of code that used empty span in between text node to track position of each word, as shown in the example.

Comment: @Takechiyo, then you may want to take it up with the Chrome developers. Firefox Developer tools show the empty span between `a` and `sentence` even without the added style.

Comment: Yep I already reported the issue to Chrome. Was just hoping someone here know something about this behavior.